# Edit Forms of all entity's object in one page Symfony3

Tags: php, forms, twig, symfony

I want to have edit forms to all object in one view.

Already, I have this effect: [image: PICTURE]

But when I try to edit a simple object, it doesn't work.

**Corrections.html.twig**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nazwa poprawki</th>
                    <th>Status dla</th>
                    <th>Status dla klienta</th>
                    <th>Nazwa projektu</th>
                    <th>Klient</th>
                    <th>Obszar</th>
                    <th>Piorytet</th>
                    <th>Data utworzenia</th>
                    <th>Iteracja</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {% for correction in corrections %}
                    {{ form_start(form[loop.index0]) }}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{correction.correctionName}}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(form[loop.index0].adminStatusCorrectionId) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(form[loop.index0].userStatusCorrectionId) }}</td>
                        <td>{{correction.projectId.projectName}}</td>
                        <td>{{correction.projectId.userId.firstName}} {{correction.projectId.userId.lastName}}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(form[loop.index0].areaId) }}</td>
                        {% if correction.priority %}
                            <td>Tak</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td>Nie</td>
                        {% endif %}
                        <td>{{correction.creationDate|date('Y-m-d')}}</td>
                        <td>{{correction.iteration}}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(form[loop.index0].save) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </form>
                    {{ form_end(form[loop.index0]) }}
                {%endfor %}

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AdministratorController.php**

```
public function correctionsAction(Request $request) {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Correction');
    $corrections = $repository->findAll();

    foreach ($corrections as $key => $value) {
        $form = $this->createForm(CorrectionType::class, $corrections[$key]);
        $formView[] = $form->createView();
    }
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $correction = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($correction);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_view_corrections');
    }

    return $this->render('administrator/corrections.html.twig', array(
                'corrections' => $corrections,
                'form' => $formView
    ));
}
```

**CorrectionType.php**

```
class CorrectionType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('adminStatusCorrectionId', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:AdminStatusCorrection',
                    'choice_label' => 'statusName'
                ))
                ->add('userStatusCorrectionId', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:UserStatusCorrection',
                    'choice_label' => 'statusName'
                ))
                ->add('areaId', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Area',
                    'choice_label' => 'areaName'
                ))
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Aktualizacja'))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Correction::class,
        ));
    }

}
```

What can I do now ?

**EDIT**

All of my form have "correction" name.

In this case i have got 12 forms:

```
<form name="correction" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: Can you give us the error you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the form handling inside your foreach cycle, also you need to give different name to each of your forms, so you could use the createNamed() method of the 'form.factory':

```
foreach ($corrections as $key => $value) {
    $formName = 'form_' . $key;
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed($formName, CorrectionType::class, $corrections[$key]);

    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST' && $request->request->has($formName)) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    }

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $correction = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($correction);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_view_corrections');
    }

    $formView[] = $form->createView();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
When i edit one row, every rows are edited. So where is the problem now ? :)

Comment: Can you tell me how to use createNamed() method of the 'form.factory' ? I tried it many times and it didn't work :/

Comment: The problem is that all the forms have the same name and the handleRequest() method cannot identify which one is submitted. I updated the answer to use the createNamed() method of the 'form.factory' service, so that you can set different name to each form. Then you can check which form was submitted. Check my answer for the updated code.

Comment: Thanks, mate ! :)